# Breadth First and Depth First Searches in Directed Graph

Tags: depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

[Graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZccs.png)

Starting at node A. If I were to traverse this graph using BFS and DFS, would the traversal just stop once it reaches node E because there are no arrows coming out of E? If this is the case then the output would just be [A,D,E] for both types of searches?